# Fixed SQL Query if paramerter empty also incluce NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the following where condition in a fixed sql query:

```
and ([NC_DATA].WORK_CENTER_BO LIKE '%[Param.4]%' OR '[Param.4]' IS NULL)
```

and its working fine when I enter a value for Param.4, but when I don't use Param.4 it's not giving the NULL paramter only data with values. How can I achieve that I get data with values and also data = NULL

Thanks for helping!

What I tried:

```
and ([NC_DATA].WORK_CENTER_BO LIKE '%[Param.4]%' OR '[Param.4]' IS NULL)
```

I get:

| Column 1 | WORK_CENTER_BO |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 |
| DEF | 456 |

I expecting:

| Column 1 | WORK_CENTER_BO |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 |
| DEF | 456 |
| GHI | NULL |

Comment: 1. Don't embed parameters into string literals of SQL statements. Use bind variables instead. 2. As long as we don't know your application, we couldn't know how `NULL` value for `Param.4` is serialized into string (because you use SQL injection to pass parameters). So the result of `... '[Param.4]' ...` is unknown and it's hard to guess if it is null or not (in Oracle empty string is also null)

Comment: You need to use WORK_CENTER_BO is NULL

Comment: Please post an actual query (or at least this part of the `where` clause) that is executed in at DB side. You may obtain it from `v$sql` view, it will contain a substituted value of `... '[Param.4]' IS NULL` (unless `cursor_sharing=force` is set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm) function as follows:

```
and (COALESCE([NC_DATA].WORK_CENTER_BO, '[Param.4]') LIKE '%[Param.4]%')
```

If your "*WORK_CENTER_BO*" is null, it will be replaced with `[Param.4]` to match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
AND (([NC_DATA].WORK_CENTER_BO LIKE '%'||NVL('[Param.4]',[NC_DATA].WORK_CENTER_BO)||'%') OR [NC_DATA].WORK_CENTER_BO IS NULL)
```

a rule of a thumb: **All comparisons with NULL resolve to false.**

Comment: It is not true. `where` admits only rows with `TRUE` condition value, everything that is not `TRUE` is filtered out. `NULL = <anything>` is `UNKNOWN`, so is not `TRUE` and is not returned by the query. See [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Conditions.html#GUID-C2E3ED44-16E7-4924-9125-E1693B1022A8). `not(false)` returns `true` while `not(null = <anything>)` does not

Comment: I had in mind all comparisons =,<,> apart from using `IS`, `IS NOT` will not be satisfied, probably my wording is not suitable.